# If God stopped the disrobing of Draupadi then why doesn't he stop the disrobing of every woman?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, kali-yuga, draupadi

If God protected Draupadi then why don't he protect every other women?

Comment: Because not every woman is Draupadi. Draupadi was not just some ordinary woman she was a great Bhakta who worshipped Lord Krishna as her Brother. Some even consider her avatar of someone. But all in all she was highly saintly woman.

Comment: As for other i think it's part of prarabdha karma. All we can do is pray to God to reduce our suffering.

Comment: Do you have any proof that prarabdha karma or in general law of karma works? @RishX

Comment: yes there is plenty of Shastric evidence for it.

Comment: Can you give me some evidence or make some references please?@RishX